# Por qué el return es None en esta funcion?

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo que hacer una funcion que valide el formato de un codigo LetraNumero-NumNum, por ejemplo D4-27 y que de estar correcto me devuelva la zona a la que corresponde el codigo. Creo que finalmente logré que funcionara sin embargo mi resultado, donde debería ir el print de la zona lo que recibo es None. ¿Qué podría hacer?

```
import re

#4 Ubicando a los nuevos ingresos…

def validarCodigo(codigo):
    if re.match("^[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]{1}[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]{1}[-][0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]{2}$", codigo):
        return True
    elif re.match("^$", codigo):
        print("Debe especificar un código, vuelva a ingresar el código nuevamente.")
        return False
    else:
        print("Código de aula incorrecta, debe especificar un código, vuelva a ingresar el código nuevamente.")
        return False

def ubicarAula(codigo):
    if re.match("^[A,B,E].*",str(codigo)):
        return "noroeste"
    elif re.match("^[C,D,I].*",str(codigo)):
        return "suroeste"
    elif re.match("^[F,G,H].*",str(codigo)):
        return "sureste"

def obtenerCodigo():
    entrada = False
    while entrada == False:
        entrada = validarCodigo(input("Enter your class code: "))
    print(ubicarAula(entrada))
    return ""
```

obtenerCodigo()

Comment: Tienes errores de sintaxis, y ¿de cual función estamos hablando?

Comment: Pues tengo que, al final de todo recibir como salida el return de la funcion ubicarAula, ya sea Noroeste, Suroeste o Sureste. Acabo de agregar una pequeña modificación porque en ubicarAula solo funcionaba si codigo en re.match lleva string antes.

Comment: La función `ubicarAula`, cuando el código no cumple ninguna de las condiciones no se aplica ningun `return`, por lo que retorna `None`

Comment: Para especificar un digito en la expresión regular, usa '\d', que es más corto.

Comment: Pero cuando ingreso, por ejemplo, D4-27 debería retornar Suroeste, pero retorna None, es lo que no entiendo. Si ingreso algo que no las cumple tengo las funciones que se encargan de eso.

Comment: \d en lugar de los numeros de 0 a 9?

Comment: El "^" al comienzo de la expresión regular es redundante si usas `match`, pues `match` busca calzar desde el comienzo del string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí hay dos problemas, el primero es que tienes un error de sintaxis en `elif re.match("^[F,G,H].*",codigo)):` falta cerrar el paréntesis en codigo

`elif re.match("^[F,G,H].*",(codigo)):`

El segundo y más importante, en la función `ubicarAula` acepta de parámetro código, y tú en código le estás pasando `entrada` que lo defines como boleado de inicio, y en la función validar código, regresa un booleano.

```
# entrada es booleano
entrada = False
while entrada == False:
    # entrada sigue siendo un booelano pues retornas un booleano en validar codigo
    entrada = validarCodigo(input("Enter your class code: "))
print(ubicarAula(entrada))
```

por lo que tendrías que hacer el match del código ingresado, se puede hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
while entrada == False:
    codigo = input("Enter your class code: ")
    entrada = validarCodigo(codigo)
print(ubicarAula(codigo))
```

De esta forma guardas el código entrado en una variable, lo validas, y si es válido, lo usas para `ubicarAula`

Comment: Voy a probarlo, no se me hubiera ocurrido eso antes. Gracias

Comment: Me funcionó, muchísimas gracias!